# External embedded css in index.html missing after docker build

Tags: html, css, docker, npm, webpack

I have a Vue/Webpack application that uses an external-referencing, embedded CSS link in my `index.html` file. It looks something like:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico" />
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900"
    />
   ...
  </head>
```

If I run `npm run build` in the project directory, the resulting `dist/index.html` file will contain this link.

However, I am deploying my project in a Docker container. At the end of that container building process, this CSS link and others like it will be gone in the generated `index.html` file, causing several elements on my page to break graphically.

What settings in the webpack/Docker config could cause this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution - it seems that my Dockerfile included a copy of the `src` and `resources` folders for the working directory, but not the `public` folder which contained the favicon as well as the base `index.html`.  This meant that the `index.html` that was autogenerated as part of `npm run build` would never take the above lines of code into account.